# Why can’t I play Minecraft Java Edition anymore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can’t play Minecraft Java Edition anymore - when I log into the Minecraft Launcher, it says that I have to buy Minecraft again. What do I do?

I use Debian Linux.

Answer (score 2):

## Update:

The page https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition now has another button labelled `Already own Minecraft? Download it again`. You can click the button right there to download the Minecraft launcher. When prompted by the app, just sign in!
[image: download]
And yes, this button works even if you aren't signed in. If you click it without owning Minecraft, you'll be stopped by the app itself when you are requested to sign in.

---

## Old answer

The [minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net) website does not change, even when logged in with an account that already owns Minecraft. Make sure you're logged into the Minecraft website, then follow the links to purchase Minecraft until you reach the purchase store:
[image: Already Owns Minecraft]
From there, just click the appropriate download button and run the installer files that come with it. When prompted by the launcher program, simply login using your existing account.

Worlds are saved per device, not per account. This means the worlds on your old device will not be transferred to your new computer. Mojang does not provide a cloud backup, so you'll need to find your own. If your old hard drive is unrecoverable, you may not be able to get those worlds back!